# DE org for superbadges - not receiving email

Tags: trailhead, developer-org

I am not being able to sign up for the new Developer Edition org, a necessary step before starting with superbadge challenges, because after submitting form completion I am not receiving an email for activation of org.

Has anyone faced this issue recently or have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I would suggest you to open a Trailhead case with Salesforce - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=feedback#cfPanel

Comment: I will recommend to contact Salesforce support. You can find out how to do it by clicking the link below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but have you double checked your email address and double checked your spam folder?

Comment: @MattLacey, yeah I did that too but still the same. I opened a case though and now I'm waiting from trailhead team to fix it, hopefully.

Comment: Even I am having the same issue I have not got any mail from salesforce even after continuously signing up for the superbadge challenge. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In case someone face the same issue, try to signup choosing different location.
That's how I manage to resolve this, while waiting for trailhead support team.